# Restricting listen port access

Tags: linux, networking

I'm trying to create a sandbox to run untrusted user code and I would like to allow users to listen on a network socket (on Linux). But I would like to limit what ports they can listen on. I have tried apparmor, but apparmor only provides an option to completely disable tcp connections. I need a more fine grained policy.

I have also tried ptrace, but was only able to intercept the sys_socketcall syscall but was not able to get the port number. Besides, I know ptrace is not entirely secure so that would not be a proper solution.

Here is the code that I have been trying to use to intercept the port number supplied to bind:

```
params[0] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                         child, 4 * EBX,
                         NULL);
params[1] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                         child, 4 * ECX,
                         NULL);
params[2] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                         child, 4 * EDX,
                         NULL);


printf("SYS_socketcall called with %u\n", (int)params[0]);  
if(params[0] == 2){ // SYS_BIND
    int call = params[0]; 
    int *args = (intptr_t*)params[1]; 
    int socket = args[0]; 
    struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)args[1]; 
    int len = args[2]; 
    //struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)args[1]; 

    printf("BIND CALLED WITH call: %d, fd: %d, addr: %p\n", call, socket, addr);
}
```

but it segfaults because I must be doing something wrong when getting the pointer to the sockaddr struct that is passed to the syscall. According to http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html the second parameter in ECX is a pointer to argument list where arguments are [socket_fd, sockaddr*]. But it doesn't work. why?

Is there a better way to do this than with ptrace?

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/344161/restrict-user-access-to-certain-ports

Answer (score 1):

SELinux will allow you to restrict processes very tightly, including port access. It even comes with a [`sandbox`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sandbox) command that can run a process in a very restricted sandbox domain, to which you can then replace with a customized domain in order to provide access to files and ports as appropriate.